# Can insect repellents kill insects?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

One day, there was a fly in my house. I really hate insects flying around me, but I don't want to catch it with my hands, so I sprayed some insect repellent directly onto the fly to try to get rid of it.

This is the insect repellent that I used.

[image]

Sticker reads:

> "*Wirkstoff basierend auf Zitronen-eucaluptusöl*"
>
> ---
>
> "Active ingredient based on lemon-eucalyptus oil"

When the insect repellent hits the fly, it slowed down and stopped flying, but it's still moving slowly on the window, so I applied the insect repellent again.

Eventually, the fly completely stopped moving, so I assume it's dead. Does the insect repellent actually killed the fly, or just stunned it?

Comment: I think it's only repellent and isn't for spraying insects directly. You don't have fly swatter?

Comment: This Wikipedia page on "Insect repellent"  pretty much says everything in the first two paragraphs [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_repellent ] ;)

Comment: According to the sticker on the cap, the active ingredient is "Lemon-eucalyptus oil". I don't think that's insecticidal (but certainly an insect *repellent*). Of course, too much of anything would kill anything...which means your fly is probably dead ;) (What's written on the can isn't really important...)

Comment: There was some foam in the insect repellent, so there may be some surfactant.

Comment: I mean, it probably could disorient it enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Wikipedia article on ["Insect repellent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_repellent) pretty much answers your question.

---

An insect *repellent* isn't necessarily the same as an [*insecticide*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insecticide).

The repellent, well, "repels" insects; i.e- it discourages them from approaching you (or whatever you sprayed the repellent on) for as long as the chemical(s) linger. These (particularly those based on essential oils) aren't much of a health hazard to other animals.

An insecticide is actually designed to kill insects ("No sh!t Sherlock") rather than simply keeping them at bay. The term "insecticide" refers to substances that kill insects/arthropods at very low concentrations ( "very low" is subjective... I don't think there's an authoritative, precise definition for "insecticides" anyway).

---

FYI, *any* substance (including common stuff like air and  [water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67874/can-drinking-a-lot-of-water-be-fatal)), supplied in excess (again, "excess" is also highly subjective) can kill. Ever heard of "*Too much of anything can kill*"?

The opposite effect is something called ["Hormesis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormesis); where just the right amount of *anything* (including radiation and toxins) can have a *positive* effect on you.

---

Back to question.

The insect repellent you're using contains (according to the sticker on the cap) [lemon-eucalyptus oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corymbia_citriodora), whose active ingredient is [p-menthane-3,8-diol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-Menthane-3,8-diol) (and its geometrical isomers). Also, it's supposed to be used against mosquitoes (*Mücken*) and ticks (*Zecken*).

It serves as a deterrent, on account of how strong it smells.

Ectoparasitic insects, such as the said mosquitoes and ticks, rely on (to a large extent) their sense of "smell" to locate hosts. So spraying around strong odorants will do a good job of interfering with the bug's ability to track you down.

Remember my "anything can kill" rant from earlier? Well, the same goes for your repellent. If I were a mosquito or a tick (or whatever insect for that matter), I doubt I'd make it out alive if you decided to smother me with some godforsaken liquid/aerosol. For all I know, your fly could've died because it *suffocated*, rather than being *poisoned*.

Heck, you could achieve the same effect if you decided to drown the fly in deodorant or even perfume.

So there isn't really much behind the mysterious death of your fly; in all likelihood it suffocated (You murderer!). Take @Mithoron's advice; a fly swatter works better.

If you want to know what biochemical processes the repellent would tamper with in a bug, then that's a question for the Biology.SE. ;)

Comment: I heard that surfactants can block the pores that insects use for breath. Maybe that's how it killed the fly.

Comment: @Zen Maybe, maybe not. Surfactants (if added) are present in minute quantities. The repellent (as a whole) is a liquid... there's really no point in trying to specify what blocked the spiracles (the "pores" insects breathe through) since you're dealing with a solution (homogeneous mixture of multiple liquids). If this answer helped, you can up-vote it. Also, you can consider ticking the "Accept answer" button. Cheers!

Comment: Even if it didn't actually killed the fly, it did certainly stunned the fly because it completely stopped moving after few more sprays.

Comment: @Zen Yup, it's clear that death wasn't instant (the first few sprays incapacitated/"stunned" it)...and  I'm also pretty sure the fly didn't get back up afterwards ;P

Comment: Today, another fly has appeared, so I had another chance to test my insect repellent. It appeared at afternoon. I applied the spray to the fly. At first, it has convulsions, but then it completely stopped quickly. It's night now, and it's still there, so I am sure it's dead.

Comment: @Zen Your zeal for conducting field experiments is laudable (well, you probably might not think of it as an "experiment", but it *is*). Just a pointer though, using repellent to *kill* flies is a waste, you should settle for either a swatter or (commercially available) insecticide sprays ;P

Comment: it does kills the fly, so I don't think it's complete waste